# Changing the size of UIStepper

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uistepper

I can't seem to change the size of `UIStepper`:

1. In IB, the Width and Height boxes are grayed out.
2. I used `initWithFrame`:

   UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 638, 120, 80)];

   But it does not change the size.  Several posts on SO seemed to implied it is changeable.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the doc:

> The bounding rectangle for a stepper matches that of a UISwitch object.

Doesn't sound, like it is possible upfront.

Also in this [blog post](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uistepper-control.html):

```
// Frame defines location, size values are ignored
UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 20, 0, 0)];
```

But you can try to [transform it's layer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-TPXREF101).

Answer (score 6):

```
UIStepper* s = [UIStepper alloc] init];  
s.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can properly update the UIStepper size without transformation.

Use the following method to set the background image and the stepper will draw itself using the background size:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

**Example**

```
    [self.stepper1 setIncrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plusIcon1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.stepper1 setDecrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"minusIcon1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.stepper1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperBkg1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.stepper1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperBkgHighlighted1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.stepper1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperBkgDisabled1.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

This yields the following result on the left, compared to an unmodified stepper on the right:
[image]

stepperBkg1@2x.png:

[image]

stepperBkgHighlighted1@2x.png:

[image]

Comment: The important bit here is that the background image is the one setting the size of the UIStepper.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the transform on my stepper - it did change the appearance and did scale it, however, the images of the + and - were stretched (so you have to scale in proportion to the original stepper.

Also, be careful because the area of touch that actually increments and decrements, does change - so on the stretched image, the button would not decrement along the entire view - so this is probably not a good solution....

Answer (score 1):

You can provably scale it:

```
stepper.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.75, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a small custom UIStepper class for it. No images needed, no transformation needed. Images generated automatically.
https://github.com/alelipona/VZCustomSizeStepper
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can change size of stepper.

first, right click on storyboard --> select (open as)--> Select (Source Code)

then find stepper in the code--> find width=??? and change.

then click on storyboard again and select open as interface builder.